# MySQL: How to efficiently bulk upsert rows, based on previous value?

Tags: mysql, sql

So let's say I have a table `prices`:

| key | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 'a' | 5 |
| 'c' | 6 |

meanwhile, in app memory, I aggregate a list of updates:

| key | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 'a' | 10 |
| 'c' | 3 |
| 'foo' | 8 |

and I wish to update it, by adding a specific value to the cost in each row.
So for example, for row 'a' I would want:

```
UPDATE `products` SET cost = cost + 10 where key = 'a';
```

I would also like to insert any non existing rows.

Only issue is, I want to do so in bulk. I think about 1000 rows at a time is a good value that should fit in mysql query length limitation.

After much googling and stack-overflow-ing, I ended up with this:

```
INSERT into products 
SELECT updates.key, coalesce(p.cost, 0) + updates.cost as cost
FROM (
    VALUES
        ROW ('a', 10),
        ROW ('c', 3),
        ROW ('foo', 8)
) AS updates (`key`, `cost`)
LEFT JOIN products p on p.`key` = updates.`key`()
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE products.cost = products.cost + updates.`count`
```

Issues I have with this query:

1. double logic - `coalesce(p.cost, 0) + updates.cost` and `products.cost = products.cost + updates.`count`
2. That join in there bothers me, feels a bit unnecessary.

Is there a better way to do this?

(I know that "general" not specific questions are not great for stack overflow, but I think this is an interesting use case.)

Comment: VALUES is a DML statement introduced in MySQL 8.0.19 - what version are you on? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Comment: I'm on 8.0.23 (latest) via docker as this is still in the personal project realm and not a serious production.
If you have a suggestion that is relevant for MySQL 5.7 I would gladly accept/upvote it :)

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN is excess.

Comment: You should not develop in a higher version than production the row feature is too new for you.AND docker is not tagged or mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`VALUES()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) to use the value being inserted:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE products.cost = VALUES (cost)
```

I'm not sure why you are bothered by the `JOIN`.  It does what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
INSERT INTO products 
SELECT updates.key, updates.cost
FROM (
    VALUES
        ROW ('a', 10),
        ROW ('c', 3),
        ROW ('foo', 8)
) AS updates (`key`, cost)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE products.cost = products.cost + updates.cost;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d56176450d652e292138e1714c23d8bc)